# Check if all children elements are hidden

Tags: jquery, visibility

I'm a bit stuck here with my script:

Its a checkbox filtering all `.notme` images and hiding it's list items.
The problem is now I cant get a working callback function for the `fadeToggle`.
It should behave like this :

> If all children of `#list-team-single-container` are "displayed none" - do something.

```
$('#show-only-my-teams').change(function(){
    $('.notme').each(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().fadeToggle('fast', function(){
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Any mark up, as in children?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
if($('#list-team-single-container').children(':visible').length == 0) {
   // action when all are hidden
}
```

Comment: Plus one, but I would recommend using `===` over `==`.

Comment: Note that :visible means that it's taking up space on the page. If it's nested within hidden elements and not currently displayed it will not be seen as :visible. If you're wanting to make sure it's not "display:none" this might not suffice.

Comment: what if I am checking against a style? `display: none` or `display: block`? It works for none but for block it doesn't.

Comment: @Si8 You can check the attribute of the children(?)

Answer (score 10):

The `:visible` jQuery selector might be what you are looking for...

From the [description](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document.
>   Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.
>
> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible,
>   since they still consume space in the layout. During animations that
>   hide an element, the element is considered to be visible until the end
>   of the animation. During animations to show an element, the element is
>   considered to be visible at the start at the animation.

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

---

```
$('#list-team-single-container').children(':visible');
```

That line of code will return all of the child elements of `#list-team-single-container` that are visible.

```
$('#list-team-single-container').children(':visible').length;
```

That line of code will return **the number of child elements** of `#list-team-single-container` that are visible.

Answer (score 9):

It's difficult to be specific without seeing your markup, but I'd imagine doing something like this:

```
var isVisible = 0;

$('.notme').each( function() {
    if( $(this).is(":visible") {
         isVisible++;
    }
});

if ( isVisible == 0 )
    // do something
```

Comment: You might want to refactor your example... `error` is not really the right way to represent that variable... `visibleItems` perhaps...  Giving it the `error` variable name is a little confusing.  There is no error actually occurring...

Comment: True, but in my mind it, being visible instead of hidden, is an error in the logic I was creating. So, I put error. =)

Comment: Ah! There you go - in **your** mind - what about others that come to read your code? Case in point :P

Comment: I'll bribe you with an upvote to change that variable name ;)  Just say thank you that I'm not black mailing you with a downvote! haha