# jQuery change function for hidden child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a page that shows and hides elements based on filters-- that is, sets list items to `display:block` or `display:none` based on criteria-- and I'd like to display a message when *no items* are being shown (e.g. "sorry, no elements match your criteria".) If my list looks like this:

```
<ul class="list">
   <li class="item">Item 1</li>
   <li class="item">Item 2</li>
   <li class="item">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I've tried the following `change` function based on this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382353/check-if-all-children-elements-are-hidden):

```js
$("body").on('change', function() {
  if ($('.list').children(':visible').length == 0) {
    console.log('none visible');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="item">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

But it doesn't seem to be working? Any assistance here is much appreciated.

Comment: I think there is nothing what triggers your event listener. When body changes? I think you want to show it, when page is loaded, so just remove the `$("body").on('change', function() {` wrapper.

Comment: @karacsi_maci I'm using the event listener because the items in `.list` are being dynamically filtered (set to `display:none` or `display:block`) on different selections...

Comment: how would the change event fire if the list options are all hidden?

Comment: Yes, I see, but when `body` has changed???

Comment: If this is supposed to fire when the filters have changed, we need to see the filters.  Or, we need to know the class assigned to the filters and the type of input they are.

Comment: @devlincarnate - thanks, I'm clearly approaching this the wrong way. My filters are anchors within divs with the class `filter`, so jQuery selector `.filter a`-- and basically, on click, if no elements with class of `.item` are visible, I'd like the alert to show (and otherwise be hidden.) I'm ultimately going to include a text block that shows/hides based on this state.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown us the filters that trigger the change event, so I've made up an example input filter:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="item">Item 3</li>
</ul>
<input type="text" class="filter">
```

To trigger the event and log when no list items are visible:

```
$(".filter").on("blur", function() {
  if ($('.list').children(':visible').length == 0) {
    console.log('none visible');
  }
});
```

[Here is a Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4dmvsck9/).

Of course, you may need to adjust the type of event -- it depends on what type of element the filters are.  In my example, I used an input element, and so `blur` is an appropriate event.

If your filters are link elements inside a div with class `filter`, then `click` would be an appropriate event.

```
$(".filter a").on("click", function() { ...
```

Comment: @nickpish - I see the logging after clicking Moscow.  After clicking Human Resources, I see an error.  I'd recommend that you use console logging in your event to verify the event is triggering (so put it as the first line in the function), and then to inspect the content of `$('.list').children()` to see why the condition isn't being met.

Answer (score 0):

I may have missed something, but if sounds like you could always just do a simple `length` check when the page loads.

```
if ($('.list li').length = 0) {
 console.log('none visible');
}
```

http://codepen.io/justdan/pen/EggZQx

Comment: thanks for the response; but I need to run the check when the filters have been clicked, affecting the visibility of the list items dynamically-- this only seems to fire on page load

Comment: Ah yes that's true. Here's a quick fiddle with a possible idea. If you can match the `li's` you filter out and `.remove()` them, you can get an updated list length dynamically. https://jsfiddle.net/9hxazkoc/