# CSS pseudo-class like :empty , but also ignores hidden children

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

The [`:empty` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) represents any element that has no children at all. Is there a similar pseudo-class that represents any element that has no visible children (ignoring children with `display` set to `none`)?

If there isn't a pseudo-class that does this, is there a way to achieve this filtering using CSS?

Comment: @dippas Thanks for reopening :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS selection is a one-directional tree. Once you get down to the children, you can no longer act on the parent.

You need to check for the `display: none;` property on all the children to know if they are all hidden or not. You can select all hidden children like so: `<parent tag> *[display=none]`. However, there's no way to know if **all** the children are hidden and there's no way to re-select the parent once you've identified the hidden children.

In order to accomplish this, you will need to use JavaScript. See this: [Check if all children elements are hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382353/check-if-all-children-elements-are-hidden)

Answer (score 1):

With the *new* css selector `:has()` you can do something like this:

```
parent:has(children[style*="display: none"])
```

where **parent** is the container selector and **children** the selector for the element on which check for the display.