# How to hide a div with a child with `display: none` style?

Tags: html, css, frontend

To hide empty div, I use pseudo-class `:empty`.

I need to hide not only empty div, but also a div with a child with `display: none` style. It only looks empty, in fact it has an `html` code.

Is there a way to hide such a block?

I would like to use only `css`

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: purple;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}
div:empty{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<br>Div:
<br><div>123</div>
<br><br>
<br>Div with a space:
<br><div>&nbsp;</div>
<br><br>
<br>Empty div (hidden, it is simple):
<br><div></div>
<br><br>
<br>Div with block:
<br><div>
  <section>456</section>
</div>
<br><br>
<br>Div with block with a style display:none(how to hide it with css use only?):
<br><div>
  <section style="display: none;">789</section>
</div>
<br><br>
```

Comment: no way to do this with empty or css simply. You will have to use jquery.

Comment: If you add ```display: none``` to child why you cannot add it to the parent div you want to hide?

Comment: Can't be done via CSS unfortunately. but [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10382439/4341456) a nice JS way

Comment: @pkolawa so, in my project i cant't do this. I am curious can i do this simpli? pseudo-class could be perfect, but it doesn't work for div with child

Comment: @Daniel thank you for this link! But i'll wait a bit, maybe there is a way, or some kind of hack

Comment: @Daniel the statement about `can't be done via CSS` is not completely true. There is a `:host-context` pseudo class, which finds the closest parent for the defined selector. Though it is used only within the `shadow-tree` -> https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping/#selectordef-host-context

Comment: Describe your actual problem, not a facet of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution with `:has`, but it doesn't work in all browsers (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has)

```
div:has(> section[style*="display:block"]) {
    display: none;
}
```

So, I can use solution with `jQuery`:

```
$("div:has(section[style*=`display:block`]").hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to check it is as many others said by jQuery (assuming that `display: none` is only inline CSS attribute:

```
if ($(element).prop("style")["width"] !== ''){
  $(this).parent().css("display", "none");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something but why not use a class for this? Then use the class to target anything you want to display:none?

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: purple;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
 
<br><div class="hide">
  <section class="hide">789</section>
</div>
<br><br>
```